# Show user info after login AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building an AngularJS application and I would like to show user info in the header of the page when user is logged in. Something like "Welcome,{{username}}".

I have created a SessionHandler service where I keep the information about the user.

```
module Shared{
    export class SessionHandler implements ISessionHandler {

            loggedUser: string;

            SetLoggedUser(user: string) {
                this.loggedUser = user;
            }

            GetLoggedUser(): string {
                return this.loggedUser;
            }
     }
}
angular.module("MainApp").service("SessionHandler", Shared.SessionHandler);
```

I have tried creating a directive

```
angular.module("MainApp").directive("myheader", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/app/shared/partials/header.html",

        controller: function ($scope, SessionHandler: Shared.ISessionHandler) {

            $scope.LoggedUser = function () {
                SessionHandler.GetLoggedUser();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

my header template is simple..

```
  <span>{{LoggedUser()}}</span>
```

my main app module looks like this

```
angular.module("MainApp", ['ui.bootstrap','Login', 'Module2'])
    ...
    .run(($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $location: ng.ILocationService, SessionHandler: Shared.ISessionHandler) => {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", (event, next, current) => {
            if (!SessionHandler.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
            if (next.templateUrl == "/app/module/login/partials/login.html") {
                SessionHandler.ClearSession();
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

and my login Controller which is in Login module calls a method on the server and after successful login sets logged user by calling SetLoggedUser() method on SessionHandler.

my index

```
<html data-ng-app="MainApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <myheader></myheader>

        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start my application logged user is empty so I only see Welcome (I will fix this later) but after I login I am redirected to another partial view but nothing changes in the header.
I am obviously missing something but I just can't figure out what.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your header directive you are missing the dependency or you can say reference to your SessionHandler service.

Can you try to add that and check what happens next..